# Spring Environment to System Properties for logback.xml

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring boot currently support the following Spring Environment to System properties for logging:

Spring Environment  System Property

```
logging.file     <----->    LOG_FILE
logging.path   <----> LOG_PATH
PID  <-----> PID
```

I want to add additional custom  Spring Environment properties , to be read in logback.xml, to be specific i want to add **LOG_KAFKA_BROKERS** <------> **LOG_KAFKA_BROKERS** to the KAFKA log appender
and in logback.xml has the following

```
<producerConfig>bootstrap.servers= ${LOG_KAFKA_BROKERS}</producerConfig>
```

What should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

It's currently not supported by spring boot but there is an open request to have it in the next release (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1788).

To get around it, I created a small library (https://github.com/lukashinsch/spring-boot-extended-logging-properties) that allows you to add arbitrary configuration properties to logback.xml via application.properties/yml.

Comment: Thanks I will also track down the issue's progress